# Laravel use alias class names from parent in child class

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a possibility to use alias class names -defined in the Parent class(abstract)- in the Child class(concrete)?

I'm trying to do just that, but I'm getting an Exception like this:

> Class 'App\Core\Carnivore' not found

Example

```
namespace App\Core; 

use  App\Services\CarnivoreService as Carnivore;

abstract class Animal
{
   abstract protected function getAnimalCollection($name);
}
```

```
namespace App\Core;

use App\Core\Animal;

class Tiger extends Animal
{
    protected function getAnimalCollection($name)
    {
        return Carnivore::findAllByName($name);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you put use  `App\Services\CarnivoreService as Carnivore;` inside the class ? :)

Comment: That is a solution but I want to have it in the abstract class so that the child classes are kept clean. My actual software program is using must more Child classes and Service Class. So I want my program not to be redundant.